# PHP cURL request to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I need to convert this PHP cURL request to JavaScript. I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing it.

I basically need to make this request be client sided instead of server sided.

```
function createSite($template_id) {
//create array with data    
$data = array("template_id"=>$template_id);

//turn data into json to pass via cURL
$data = json_encode($data);

print $data;
//Set cURL parameters
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, 
CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.duda.co/api/sites/multiscreen/create');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, API_USER.':'.API_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
//execute cURL call and get template_idte data
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//check for errors in cURL
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
//decode result
$output = json_decode($output);
//return unique site_name
return $output->site_name;
```

Comment: what's the environment? in a web page? or node.js?

Comment: A web page. This is the beginning of a dudamobile plugin, which doesn't allow server sided code to be run. Thus why I need it in JS.

Comment: Seeing as you have a username and password that needs to be sent for the request you shouldn't put this client side as any user could then get your username / password for that site. There is also the possibility that that endpoint isn't cors enabled so unless using a cors proxy server you wouldn't be able to make the request anyway

Comment: I'm sorry I should have put the rest of the code in, as it is a temporary login created to create a duda website. The user will change it at a later time once the api finishes creating the site and assigning the temp user to it.